# Form variable for upload folder

Tags: php, file, upload

Okay I am almost there. I have a form that submits info and an upload as well as creates a directory. I need it to save the uploaded file to the directory that I just created. It will create the folder with the form field I used. that part works fine. I am stumbling on getting the file to save in that newly created folder.

```
 $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/images/'.$filename; //this is now but needs to be 

 $newname = dirname(__FILE__)$folder.'/'.$filename; //Not sure how to do this part
```

I get error on last one of

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/hmintcwa/public_html/admin/list/upload.php on line 58

Comment: Allowing the user to control any part of the path is a ***horrible idea***.  `folder=../../../../../../../etc/` and `filename=passwd`

Comment: add a right concatenation `dirname(__FILE__).$folder.'/'.$filename;`. You're doing in wrong fashion.

Comment: It is for a backend admin section so I'm not to worried about it. This website that I am working on is a gift for my son. He recently lost his job and he has a wife and 3 kids to take care of so he got his real estate license renewed and is doing that. This is my way of helping him it is a surprise.

Comment: Well got that part working thank you. Now where in this would I tell it to use a default file name if they don't upload a photo.

Answer (score 2):

Add a concatenate **`.`** operator here

```
<?php
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).$folder.'/'.$filename; 
           -----------------^
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have a new question.

Comment: StackOverflow does not work like this way. Open an another question and link to this and explain your problem there.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to do something I wasn't supposed to. It is the same script so I didn't realize I needed a new post.

Comment: Now I am banned from asking questions. Thank you.